# Material UI - How a Date Picker could only select month/year

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

I'm using MaterialUI in a project and I need a date picker (https://material-ui.com/demos/pickers/) that is able to only select month and year, what props should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

To make only the months available at MUI date-picker make sure to insert options bellow:

```js
<DatePicker
  label="Small picker"
  views={['month']}
  format={"MM/YY"}
  slotProps={{ textField: { size: 'small' } }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Material UI date picker docs specify that you can use a custom renderer [here](https://material-ui-pickers.firebaseapp.com/demo/datepicker).

Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mozqv539lp) for the custom renderer. You might be able to use the custom renderer with the `format` prop to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

All links here are invalid so i want to give a quick summarization on this question, Material UI has a simple functions for what you need now (using [DatePicker](https://mui.com/components/date-picker/) component), refer to official docs:
https://mui.com/components/date-picker/#views-playground

[Codesandbox example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/c1yo6?file=/demo.js)

as you can see there, adding:
views={['year', 'month']}
property to DatePicker does the trick!